# MySQL 8.0 Replication 'Unknown Database' Error Causes Replication to Stop

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I'm having an issue with replication for two Mysql servers. The master is running Mysql 5.6 and the slave is running Mysql 8.0 due to another dependency that requires at least version 8. I am only replicating one DB, for this example's sake 'my_db'. However at a certain point in the day the master runs backups and tries to update the DB 'my_db_backups'. I am not replicating this DB and I just want to ignore these SQL commands on the replica. I explicitly ignore this database in my mysql.conf file using:

```
replicate-ignore-db=my_db_backups
```

However when I restart the mysql server I continue to see an error:

```
Last_SQL_Errno: 1049
Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Unknown database 'my_db_backups'' on query. Default database: 'my_db'. Query: 'INSERT INTO my_db.`table_1` SELECT * FROM my_db_backups.`2021_01_04_17_36_22_table_1`'
```

Everything I've read seems to indicate that setting `replicate-do-db` should only execute queries related to that DB. Additionally adding an explicit ignore, `replicate-ignore-db`, I would expect to work as well but I'm having no luck.

My full mysql.conf looks like this:

```
[mysqld]
server-id=20
lower_case_table_names=1
updatable_views_with_limit=1
relay-log-index=slave-relay-bin.index
relay-log=slave-relay-bin
replicate-ignore-db=my_db_backups
replicate-ignore-table=my_db.mysql_8_incompatible_view_1
replicate-ignore-table=my_db.mysql_8_incompatible_view_2
replicate-ignore-table=my_db.mysql_8_incompatible_view_3
replicate-ignore-table=my_db.mysql_8_incompatible_view_4
replicate-wild-do-table=my_db.%
replicate-do-db=my_db
```

I have tried every combination of these replicate-do and replicate-ignore-do configurations that I can think of I've tried adding:

```
replicate-wild-ignore-table=my_db_backups.%
```

and removing:

```
replicate-ignore-db=my_db_backups
```

and I've tried putting them both in the conf file. Nothing seems to work.

I know that I can explicitly skip error 1049 which is what I may have to end up doing. I'm just pulling my hair out trying to figure out why the other configurations aren't having any effect and can't let it go.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that the statement that produces the error isn't actually writing to a table in `my_db_backups`. It's replicating an INSERT to a table in `my_db`.

```
INSERT INTO my_db.`table_1` SELECT * FROM my_db_backups.`2021_01_04_17_36_22_table_1`
```

The statement is *reading* from a table in `my_db_backups`, which it did not find on the replica.

So the statement that inserts into `my_db.table_1` will be executed on the replica, because the default database `my_db` was not ignored.

You could also fix this by using ROW-based binary logs on the master, so it doesn't matter that it's reading from a table that doesn't exist on the replica. The INSERT would result in a row image on the master, where the table does exist.

Comment: Ah, thank you that is it. I see that I misunderstood the way replicate-ignore-db works. Unfortunately I cannot change the replication type on the master. However for people reading this that can I'm trying to understand what you mean. From the docs: "Row-based format - Tells the server not to log updates to any tables in the database db_name." In my case db_name is `my_db_backups` but that is not the database that is being updated. You're saying it would work even though this is the case? I suppose for myself however skipping error 1049 is my only option here. Thanks again!

Comment: The table that is being updated is in `my_db`. But if you use row based format on the master, it wouldn't matter where the data came from, the log would just have the full row with literal values to insert into `my_db.table_1`. But if you can't change the binlog format, that's not going to work.

Comment: The only solution with statement-based replication is that you must not filter databases. Let the `my_db_backups` tables replicate. Skipping errors is not a wise solution, because it would be hard to make it _not_ skip legitimate errors.